# MYSQL não inicia após Atualização da versão 5.5 para 5.7 no server Centos 6.9

Tags: mysql, centos

Estou atualizando o Mysql 5.5 para MYSQL 5.7 no servidor Centos 6,porém após a atualização o servidor não inicia.Eu realizei o processo de remoção da versão do MYSQL 5.5 para realizar atualização como indicado em diversos foruns. Vou desrever o passo a passo de todo o processo com captura de tela, para facilitar a identificação dos possíveis erros.

1 - Realizei o download do repo para E6 11.

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2 - Fiz a instalação local

```
yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3 - Removi todos os pacotes anteriores, em relação ao MySQL 5.7

```
yum remove mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch 
yum remove compat-mysql51-5.1.73-1.el6.remi.x86_64 
yum remove mysql-libs-5.5.57-1.el6.remi.x86_64
```

4 - Instalei o MYSQL 5.7

```
yum install mysql-community-server
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5 - Reiniciei o servidor MYSQL 5.7

```
service mysqld restart
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Para tentar solucionar o problema eu tentei os seguintes procedimentos.**

1.1 - Verifiquei espaço em disco
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1.2 - Verifiquei a saída do meu RPM

```
rpm -qa | grep MySQL
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tentou remover com purge e reinstalar?

Comment: Qual comando? Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Não sei dizer qual o equivalente no CentOS, mas no ubuntu funciona assim apt-get remove --purge mysql-server, acredito que deva ser a mesma coisa, depois reinstala a vs que quiser

Comment: Na sua opinião pode ser algum arquivo que ficou corrompido na hora da remoção da versão anterior do MYSQL?

Comment: Bem isso mesmo, provavelmente a desinstalação não foi completa, ou ficou algum servico rodando no seu sistema, por isso tu não consegue iniciar a nova versão